# How to nest many-to-many objects in Python?

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm fetching data from the db from 3 different tables, and need to return them all as 1 object with other objects nested inside.

Specifically, I have an ApplicationForm object, which contains 1 to many Section objects. The Section objects in turn can contain 1 to many Question objects.

I've successfully mapped the Section to the ApplicationForm, but am having trouble with the Question objects, as they need to be mapped to the correct Sections based on their section_id attribute.

```
class ApplicationFormAPI(ApplicationFormMixin, restful.Resource):

    question_fields = {
      'id': fields.Integer,
      'type': fields.String,
      'description': fields.String,
      'order': fields.Integer
    } 

    section_fields = {
      'id': fields.Integer,
      'name': fields.String,
      'description': fields.String,
      'order': fields.Integer,  
      'questions': fields.List(fields.Nested(question_fields))   
    }

    form_fields = {
      'id': fields.Integer,
      'event_id': fields.Integer,
      'is_open':  fields.Boolean,
      'deadline': fields.DateTime,
      'sections': fields.List(fields.Nested(section_fields)) 
    }

    @marshal_with(form_fields)
    def get(self):
        req_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        req_parser.add_argument('event_id', type=int, required=True, help = 'Invalid event_id requested. Event_id\'s should be of type int.')
        args = req_parser.parse_args()

        form = db.session.query(ApplicationForm).filter(ApplicationForm.event_id == args['event_id']).first()     
        sections = db.session.query(Section).filter(Section.application_form_id == form.id)   #All sections in our form
        questions = db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.application_form_id == form.id) #All questions in our form        

        form.sections = sections

        #Need to bind the sections with their relevant questions 
        for s in form.sections:
            sec_questions = []
            for q in questions:
                if(q.section_id == s.id):
                    sec_questions.append(q)
            s.questions = sec_questions

        if form: 
            return form
        else: 
            return EVENT_NOT_FOUND
```

I'm getting back the questions as "null" in my response object.

```
{
    "deadline": "Sun, 24 Mar 2019 00:00:00 -0000", 
    "event_id": 1, 
    "id": 1, 
    "is_open": true, 
    "sections": [
        {
            "description": "Personal biographical info", 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Personal Details", 
            "order": 1, 
            "questions": null
        }, 
        {
            "description": "What do you do", 
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Career Info", 
            "order": 2, 
            "questions": null
        }, 
        {
            "description": "Everything else", 
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "Misc Info", 
            "order": 3, 
            "questions": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding .all() to the end of my section and question queries:

```
    sections = db.session.query(Section).filter(Section.application_form_id == form.id).all()   #All sections in our form
    questions = db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.application_form_id == form.id).all() #All questions in our form
```

Not entirely sure why this resolved the issue, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't seems right. Questions are nested to your sections field and you reference the form id which may cause empty queries or false data.

```
questions = db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.application_form_id == form.id)
```

If this is not the problem you can try to do another query when you are in the new iteration of the section. so:

```
questions = db.session.query(Question).filter(Question.id == s.id)
```

This helps to have less if, but puts more load on the database.

Comment: Hey, Question has an application_form_id attribute too that links to ApplicationForm. I did it that way to get all the questions belonging to the current form in one db call.

I tried your suggestion, and modified the loop accordingly, but it still yielded the same result, a null questions object

Comment: Can you print out the questions before appending? So we can see if there is any data.

Comment: But you could try to not make s.question equal to sec question but update it.
So s.questions.update(sec_questions)

Comment: questions definitely has data, and the data is being queried correctly because if return questions and not form then I get back the questions data.

Tried using update, but that gave the error: AttributeError: 'Section' object has no attribute 'questions'

Comment: Then try to add s.questions = [] before the update line. So there will an actual empty argument which can be used to update it

Comment: That gave the AttributeError: 'list' has no attribute 'update'

I also tried setting s.questions = [] at the beginning of the s-loop, and then in the q-loop did s.questions.append(q), and while that didnt throw any errors, it still left questions as null